# I am getting the error unexpected symbol error near '...' I have narrowed it down to somewhere in here

Tags: lua

I am super new to code writing I am working on a wow addon for a private server to display a list of text for me to read while I am playing. I have narrowed the problem to somewhere in here.

```
AAP_MTV.EventFrame:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event, ...)
if (event=="ADDON_LOADED") then
    local arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = ...;
    if (arg1 ~= "AAP-MTV") then
        return
```

Comment: You code looks syntactically correct.

Comment: Do you know what version of Lua you're working with?

Comment: If you are working on a Mac, it may have auto-replaced `...` by the ellipsis character `…`, which often looks almost identical, but is not allowed in Lua syntax